# insert in database using json jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

i want to add  data to my database by passing as a json string then using php  what i have done but adds an empty line in the database instead of adding the data that i sent and i get the alert("fail") message  where is the mistake please
here is my save function

```
function save(){
    var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
    var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
 var data = {email: eml, mdp: mp};
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function (data) {                       
                                 alert('success');
                                     }, 
                error: function () {  
                                 alert("fail");             
                                   }  
        });
```

and here is my php file insert.php

```
 <?php 
$json = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "";
$new=json_decode($json, true);
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"bd") or die ("no database");
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,mdp)  VALUES    ('".$new['email']."','".$new['mdp']."') ";
$insert=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($insert) {
echo "created ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the structure of your json string?

Comment: I believe using stringify would be unecessary and you won't be needing to use json decode

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

JS:

```
function save(){
    var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
    var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
 var data = {email: eml, mdp: mp};
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function (data) {                       
                alert('success');
            }, 
                error: function () {
                   alert("fail");    
            }      
        });
 }
```

PHP Code:

```
 <?php 
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
$mdp = isset($_POST['mdp']) ? $_POST['mdp'] : "";

$new=json_decode($json, true);
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"bd") or die ("no database");   



$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,mdp)  VALUES    ('".$email."','".$mdp."') ";
$insert=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($insert) {
echo "created ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}  


?>
```

Comment: Is that the post variables are getting in the server side?

Comment: hi i tried to get data in the php like this
    
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
     $email =  $data ->email;
     $mdp = $data ->mdp;


it adds data in data base 
but my js function still prints" fail" whats the bug u talking about please ?

Comment: Datatype means, the type of data that you're expecting back from the server. So in the serverside use like this:

if ($insert) {
$arr['status'] = '"created ";
} else {
$arr['status'] =  "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
} 

echo json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 0):

Get data using this way in PHP

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$email =  $data ->email;
$mdp = $data ->mdp;
```

Comment: thnx alot it adds in the data base but it stills print the error message

Comment: try to remove the `dataType:'json'` from your ajax code

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP, each individual variable that you're passing through (i.e. email and mdp) is passed as individual `$_POST` data, not into a single `$_POST` variable called 'data'. Right after your opening PHP tag, check for the email and mdp:

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "");
$mdp = (isset($_POST['mdp']) ? $_POST['mdp'] : "");

$conn= ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 function save(){
        var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
        var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
     var data = {'email': eml,'mdp': mp}; //json
                $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,//pass it here
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                success: function (data) {                       

                    alert('success');
                }, 
                    error: function () {


                       alert("fail");    


                }      


            });



     }
```

php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['mdp']) {
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"bd") or die ("no database");   



$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,mdp)  VALUES    ('".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['mdp']."') ";
$insert=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($insert) {
echo "created ";
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }  
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks alot here is what i did
 i tried to get data in the php like this $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); $email = $data ->email; $mdp = $data ->mdp; it adds data in data base but my js function still prints" fail" whats the bug u

Comment: console the data from the succes function to see the php results or find the page in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
function save(){
    var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
    var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
 var data = {email: eml, mdp: mp};
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
            type: 'POST',
           // dataType: 'json',
            data: {"data":JSON.stringify(data)},
           // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function (data) {                       

                alert('success');
            }, 
                error: function () {


                   alert("fail");    

            }      

        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function save() {
    var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
    var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
    var data = {email: eml, mdp: mp};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
                //dataType: 'json',
                data: {"data": JSON.stringify(data)},
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'created')
                    alert('Success');
                else
                    alert('Fail');
            }      
        });
 }
```